# Lost remote access to my EC2 after Apache launched

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I had access to AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance using ssh key throw the 22 port. Using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart) I installed and run the http server. At that moment I couldn't open index.html remotely in the browser. Lately, I disconnected the server. Now I can see [my page](http://18.188.22.177/) but I can't login to my EC2. After scanning ports, you can see the port 22 is filtered. I asked my manager to reboot that instance but looks like apache autolaunched and port 22 for ssh is still filtered.
I didn't install any tools like ApacheGUI.

How can I fix that? I need to open port 22.

NOTE: The [ping 18.188.22.177] has no success, but the page is still alive.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Can you check your AWS security groups? If you've got port 22 limited to certain IPs there, and your IP changed, this is exactly what would happen.

Comment: check if the telnet command is working or not. try telnet <ip> 22. If it is working then the port is open to the network the issue is either with the private key you are trying to use or with the public key in the instance

Comment: @yashbagarka 
I've got 
[C:\Users\ymois>telnet 18.188.22.177 22
Connecting To 18.188.22.177...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed]
This is not about permissions. The issue is the filtered port.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted you to confirm the port is filtered. As per the earlier comment you can go to the EC2 instance and check the security groups for that port no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I found the true issue. While configuring the ufw I missed to add SSH in the firewall, so ufw locking the ssh access. The only way to fix - is to get root access, or to ask technical support to do this. But we have already killed that instance and created new.

Thanks to everyone for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added ssh in the `inbound rules` for your security group. And allow the connections from your machine by adding your public IP (`My IP`) in the column provided, or selecting `anywhere` (which is not recommended as it raises security concerns).

[image: security groups]